# how can I bind detailClass list to gridview using AJX post method with a radio button?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid with columns and radio button , i want to binddata to it using Ajax Post method.. but when I do this the radio button get disappear .. 
I want to display the List into the gridview with radionbutton at each row for selection..

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            BindGridView();

        });

        function BindGridView() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CultureHeritage.aspx/GetData",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: {},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    
                    alert(data.d); //list is here..complete table
                    

                    if (data.d.length > 0) {
                        
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                            $("#carServiceGridView").append("<tr><td></td> <td>" +
                            data.d[i].CarServiceId + "</td> <td>" +
                            data.d[i].CarServiceName + "</td> <td>" +
                            data.d[i].Address + "</td> <td>" +
                            data.d[i].Contact1 + "</td><td>" +
                            data.d[i].Contact2 + "</td><td>" +
                            data.d[i].MinimumPrice + "</td><td>" +
                            data.d[i].MaximumPrice + "</td><td>" +
                            data.d[i].NoOfCar + "</td><td>" +
                            data.d[i].CarType + "</td></tr>");
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    //alert("Error login");

                }
            });
        }
```

```html
<asp:GridView ID="carServiceGridView" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CarServiceId" Width="100%" Height="100%" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="WhiteSmoke">

                <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="carServiceGridViewRadioButton" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
               
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CarServiceId" HeaderText="Id  " />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CarServiceName" HeaderText="Service  " />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address  " />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact1" HeaderText="Contact 1  " />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact2" HeaderText="Contact 2  " />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MinimumPrice" HeaderText="Minimum Price  " />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MaximumPrice" HeaderText="Maximum Price  " />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NoOfCar" HeaderText="No Of Car  " />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CarType" HeaderText="Car Types  " />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `radio` button when you are `appending` the `rows` in `girdview` in `success` of `ajax`.

Currently when you are adding row, you are adding an empty `td` so no radio button will be shown.

Try this

```
$("#carServiceGridView").append("<tr><td><input type='radio' value='someValue' id='carServiceGridViewRadioButton"+i+"' onchange='RadioButtonSelectOne(this)' /></td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].CarServiceId + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].CarServiceName + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].Address + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].Contact1 + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].Contact2 + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].MinimumPrice + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].MaximumPrice + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].NoOfCar + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].CarType + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Check the updated answer you can append anything before or after value of `i`.

Comment: like this? 
id=' "carServiceGridViewRadioButton+ i" '..not working

Comment: <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="carServiceGridViewRadioButton" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
how to add this button? with unique ids for each row

Comment: done woking... now how to aplly ontextchange method?

Comment: For what ? Radio button doesn't have textchanged event ? It has checkedchanged event and how you want it on server side or client side ?

Comment: on client side...this is the function i want to call so that not more than one radio button is checked ................function RadioButtonSelectOne(radio) {
            checked = 1;
            radiobuttonChecked = document.getElementById(radio.id);
            var radiobuttonList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

            for (i = 0; i < radiobuttonList.length ; i++) {
                if (radiobuttonList[i].type == "radio" && radiobuttonList[i].id != radiobuttonChecked.id) {
                    radiobuttonList[i].checked = false;
                }
            }

Comment: You can use `onchange` event of radio button check the updated answer also please include any relevant code in question not in comments.